# Angular JS - Can i use separate Controllers for Tabs to load the Pane. Is it good practice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-controller

I am new to Angular JS. **Seeking experts advice and suggestions**.

1. Can I use **separate controllers** to **initialize each Tabs to load the Pane**?
2. Is it good way to give separate controllers **for Implementing Pane**? As I have DB calls in each panes of the Tab.
3. Should I use any directive.

**In my case,**
Each **Tab-Pane** will **have a form** and an **ui-grid that will display data from DB.**

Can you suggest me better ways?

**Please find my basic code for implementing Tabs with Pane.**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Bootstrap tab panel with Angular</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-class="{'active' : activeTab == 1}"><a href="" ng-click="setActiveTab(1)">One</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active' : activeTab == 2}"><a href="" ng-click="setActiveTab(2)">Two</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{'active' : activeTab == 3}"><a href="" ng-click="setActiveTab(3)">Three</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active': activeTab === 1}">Panel 1 Content</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active': activeTab === 2}">Panel 2 Content</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" ng-class="{'active': activeTab === 3}">Panel 3 Content</div>
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        angular.module("app", [])
            .controller("MainController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.activeTab = 1;

                $scope.setActiveTab = function(tabToSet) {
                    $scope.activeTab = tabToSet;
                }
            }]);
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should move to Code Review

Comment: What is wrong with the question I asked. Why was this given with negative drop. I posted the code and asked for suggestions. Come on friends.

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/125316/9357) to Code Review.

Comment: As adviced, will post similar queries to code review. Thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why you want to use multiple controllers in the first place?
2. Why do you want to use controller any how?
3. Yes you should write your own directive/wrapper to implement pane and you should call/use it from a service in angular.